# How can I handle this in cocoa? Retrieve an entry from a plist file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have this small excel file given by a brazilian government authority, it contains records for each city in Brazil, a ZIP Code range for each city and its "city code" .

I need to retrieve for a given city its "city code".

I imagine the best way would be to parse a given zip code for the city and return its "city code", based on the first two columns that display the zip code range.

I am confident that using AppleScript I can compile a plist file for the given Excel file. But can someone point me for a few lines of objectiveC code to retrieve the given entry from a plist file once I parse the ZIP code?

Please see excel file at http://www.idanfe.com/dl/codes.xls.zip

Thanks.

I have uploaded a sample plist file to http://www.idanfe.com/dl/cityCodes.plist

Further explanation:

I will parse a ZIP CODE value like: 01123010 which is in the range of 01001000 and 05895490, so my routines should return me City Code = 3550308 and City Name = São Paulo.

I have no idea how to achieve this, I might have built the sample plist wrong.

I am confident I can build a plist file using AppleScript, reading from the Excel sheet.

But retrieving the City code for a given ZIP CODE range is a puzzle.

+++ EDIT: +++

I think I have solved it, but it looks kind of clumsy, as almost everything I write.

This AppleScript reads the Excel sheet and writes the plist file : http://www.idanfe.com/dl/creating.scpt.zip

Here you find the 1 MB plist file: http://www.idanfe.com/dl/cityCodes.plist.zip

This is the code I wrote to get the City Code I need:

```
NSString *zipCodeString;
zipCodeString = @"99990000";

NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cityCodes" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *cityCodes_dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSArray *allKeys = [cityCodes_dictionary allKeys];

int i = 0;
for (i = 0 ; i <= [allKeys count]; i++) {
    NSString *someKey = [allKeys objectAtIndex:i];
    NSRange range08 = NSMakeRange (0, 8);
    NSRange range88 = NSMakeRange (8, 8);
    NSString *startZipCode = [someKey substringWithRange:range08];
    NSString *finalZipCode = [someKey substringWithRange:range88];
    int startZipCodeInt = [startZipCode intValue];
    int finalZipCodeInt = [finalZipCode intValue];

    if(startZipCodeInt <= [zipCodeString intValue] && finalZipCodeInt >= [zipCodeString intValue]){
        NSLog(@"we found a winner");
        NSString *cityCode = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[[cityCodes_dictionary objectForKey:someKey]objectForKey:@"City Code"]];

        [cityCodeIBGEField setStringValue:cityCode];
        NSLog(@"cityCode = %@",cityCode);
        break;
    } else {
       // NSLog(@"no winners");
    }
}
```

Basically I append the start zipCode and finalZip Code into one string of 16 digits, so I create one single record in the plist file.

Then when searching for the City Code I break the long key (2 zip codes) in 2 (back to normal zipCode) and search to see which record fits the given zipCode I need a cityCode for.

Some how it doesn't look the best for me, but for my own surprise the code is very fast, although in a loop.

I would appreciate comments...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I would use indexOfObjectPassingTest: to do this kind of search. Something like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cityCodes" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.cityCodes_dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    [self findCityWithZip:@"01123010"];
}

-(void)findCityWithZip:(NSString *) searchZip {
    NSUInteger indx = [self.cityCodes_dictionary.allKeys indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *zip, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *startZipCode = [zip substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 8)];
        NSString *finalZipCode = [zip substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(8, 8)];
        return (searchZip.integerValue < finalZipCode.integerValue && searchZip.integerValue > startZipCode.integerValue);
    }];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.cityCodes_dictionary valueForKey:[self.cityCodes_dictionary.allKeys objectAtIndex:indx]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the plist shouldn't be a problem at all if it is structured as a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: @"cities.plist"];
//NSString *zipStr = [dict valueForKey: @"CityNme"]; //this was an example
```

That's the easy part. The harder part is parsing and structuring the plist file from an xls file.

Or did I misunderstand your question?

PS: to get a quick look at the dictionary's plist structure, create a mock dictionary and NSLog it's description to see how it's supposed to be (or writeToFile to see the file contents or of course refer to the docs)

**edit**

You load the supplied plist file in a dictionary using the above code. Then you retrieve another dictionary from within it using

```
 NSDictionary *city = [dict valueForKey : @"yourZipCodeHere"];
```

From that dictionary you get the cityCode like this

```
NSString *cityCode = [city valueOrKey: @"City Code"];
```

As for your range problem, I'm not sure I understand it completely. But you can get an array of all the zip codes using

```
NSArray *zipArray = [dict allKeys];
```

And then you can simply iterate over that to get the correct zip code.

PS: I don't know much apple script and would be interested in how you converted the xls to plist using it.

Comment: I need to retrieve a City Code, supplying a ZIPCODE that is in a range for a given City. Please look at the sample plist file I made.

Comment: Please look for the link in my edit for scpt file I used to do the conversion.